# Python Pass Variable to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script (gcin.py) which gives me the status of a remote, 0 = down 1 = up.

```
/usr/local/bin/gcin.py -l 2010
0
```

I'm trying to run this script inside another python script (GetCut.py) using subprocess but can't get it to recognize the sys.argv[1] variable.

```
import subprocess,sys
lId=int(sys.argv[1])
p = subprocess.Popen("python /usr/local/bin/gcin.py","-l", lId, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()

if output == 1:
    print "In"
else:
    print "Out"

python GetCut.py 2010
```

Gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetCut.py", line 4, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen("python /usr/local/bin/gcin.py","-l", lId, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 660, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Try being explicit (`bufsize=lId`).

Comment: a higher-level question: Why call a python file from another python file? You can just make classes/functions that are imported from one to the other.

Comment: @JacobIRR It allows you to do two things at the same time. In this specific case it may or may not be necessary (The necessity may not be clear if this is a minimal example), but not needing to unnecessarily wait for one class method or function to finish can be a huge help with many problems. I do this all the time when doing automation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments to the subprocess with a list. You also probably don't want to use `shell=True`.

`subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/usr/local/bin/gcin.py", "-l", str(lId)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

If you only want the output of the program, you can use `check_output`:

`subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "/usr/local/bin/gcin.py", "-l", str(lId)])`

Comment: This took me to a python prompt.

Comment: ::thunder claps loudly::

Comment: Yeah... Not sure why, but that happens for me too... Fixing.